# How to avoid using hard code in java for the file address that can allow others to see it on other device?

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource

```
private void loadBkgImage()
{
    try {
        back = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/eclipse-workspace/wwk.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find image file back");

        return;
    }
```

How can I change the address that others can see the picture with their computer?

Comment: Look up “embedded resources” - probably focus on how it’s achieved in eclipse. Reading it is standard, but each ide seems to like to do it slightly differently 

Comment: What kind of application is this? Is it a Java Swing or JavaFX application.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your Image should be hosted in a place where you can access it through http, in that way you can access it in all devices. In production environments most users use Amazon S3 buckets and so on. So if you want to achieve this in your local machine, ( just for test purposes ) you should have a server where your image will be hosted on it and the link to image can be accessed through http from other users(devices).

If you need only the viewing part as a functionality, you can use [this](https://imgbb.com/)
But if you need to upload images as well, then you have to go into some other solution.

And about removing hard code part, when you are done with the http server for images, all the links you can keep them in a database or a configurations file depending on your requirement.